How to get correct tab order with nav at end of document, using only xhtml and css
My nav element is positioned at the end of the document for accessibility reasons, and positioned at the top of the screen using CSS. Because of the document order, I suspect that the nav links will be last in the tab order. Is this correct?
If so, then that will probably be undesirable to users who wish to have a logical tab order meaning that top of screen elements, ie the nav, should be first in the order. Can I somehow fix this with tabindex?
I do not have any existing tabindex attributes anywhere. I want the solution to play well with existing focusable elements eg links

I would not use tabindex because you alter the normal navigation order. If your menu is at the end of the page I would take the focus there when the page loads and continue with the normal order since it is the last element and then jump to the top of the page.
window.onload = function() { document.getElementById("nav").focus(); };

Yes, nav links will appear last in tab order. To fix this you really can use tabindex attr. Here is example:
<nav>
  <a href="#" tabindex="1">Home </a>
  <a href="#" tabindex="2">About</a>
  <a href="#" tabindex="3">Contact</a>
</nav>

Also you could try to place nav elements higher in doc order:
<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  
  <main>
    <section>
      <a href="#">Read more</a>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>


Will this play nicely with a elements in the core of the document?

Using tabindex="1" will override default tab order. With other focusable elements like form, inputs and buttons this might not play nicely, so its always best practice to keep natural flow of tab nav

I've edited my answer with alternative way

I really didn’t want the nav first for accessibility reasons. Blind users would have to suffer the nav read out first on every page. I want it to begin with the core content. this choice created the problem

Many websites use “skip to content” link which lets users pass navigation and go directly to main content

Skip/jump links are now deprecated by their inventor and rightly so in my opinion. Another repeated annoyance to be read out every time.
